# get value of an equation entered into VBA Userform Textbox to VBA variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering how to obtain the calculated value based on an equation input into a UserFrom TextBox. For example:

```
 For i=1 to xRange.count
 x = xRange(i, 1).Value
 C(i,1)= UserForm1.textbox1.Value
```

where
xRange is a range of data selected by the user from the spreadsheet
texbox1 contains an equation that user entered (e.g. x^2)

I'm trying to get the calculated value in VBA and into a matrix. However, instead of getting the value, I'm getting the equation as a string. I can trick it using the spreadsheet but I'm trying to find a solution just using VBA

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: One workaround would be to enter the formula into a cell in a worksheet, calculate it in the background and refer to this cells’ value for the result in the matrix. Also, you should use intends in your code - easier to debug and easier to read.

Comment: Writing an equation parser in VBA that analyzes a string and tries to do math based on equations found in text is a huge, non-trivial problem. Excel does what you want so don't reinvent the wheel.